# How do I made physics spring joint with angular spring

Tags: physics, godot, softbody

I'm trying to make a 3D softbody using godot 4.0 engine. I want to make a spring joint that has angular spring, because I want the softbody to expand without having a structural spring inside the softbody.

I uses hooke's law to make the linear spring but thats it, no angular spring.